# How to use Mac's java_home to pick between the same version of AdoptOpenJDK and AzulOpenJDK?

Tags: java, macos, java-home, adoptopenjdk, azul-zulu

I have in my `.zshrc` the following line which pick which JAVA_HOME it is

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*')
```

I used to only have AdoptOpenJdk, hence doing that can let me easily pick AdoptOpenJdk version 1.8

However, after installing Zulu, when I run `java_home -V`, I have the below

```
./java_home -V             
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_282 (arm64) "Azul Systems, Inc." - "Zulu 8.52.0.23" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_282 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

After that, now my JAVA_HOME which is running `/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*'` to determined is pointing to `Zulu open jdk`.

How can I get it back to AdoptJDK by just using `java_home` command?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
'unset JAVA_HOME;export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.8*')'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used free this tool in the past, it allows you to switch between different Java environments.  https://www.jenv.be/